# How to make alignment in the form?

Tags: html

It is a simple html code,when i open it in firefox,no alignment between the input lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
First name(xing): <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name(min): <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> The form itself is not visible. Also note that the default width of a text field is 20 characters.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i make alignment in the form?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align form elements in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204002/align-form-elements-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the text before the form input in a span tag and styling it:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; width:125px">First name(xing): </span>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
<span style="display:inline-block; width:125px"> Last name(min): </span>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
```

Note: you can only use the width attribute if you use the style "display:inline-block".

Another method of doing this is:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name(xing)"><br>
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name(min)"><br>
```

This is HTML5 placeholder property.